# How to build lstm network with spago package?

Tags: go, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, lstm

I'm so confusing about how to build lstm network using spago package. I was using this example https://github.com/pashh/spago/tree/63b1d96f28934a6342c4c14c5eda1cd987fbce4c/examples/progsum to build lstm model. But the example is using older spago to build lstm model. So, many function doesn't work on that example. Can somebody give me an example to build lstm network using newer spago?

I was trying to remake train that code like this
package main

```
import (
    "github.com/nlpodyssey/spago/mat/rand"
    "github.com/nlpodyssey/spago/ag"
    "github.com/nlpodyssey/spago/initializers"
    "github.com/nlpodyssey/spago/nn"
    "github.com/nlpodyssey/spago/nn/linear"
    "github.com/nlpodyssey/spago/nn/recurrent/lstm"
    // "github.com/nlpodyssey/spago/ag/fn"
    "github.com/nlpodyssey/spago/gd"
    "github.com/nlpodyssey/spago/gd/adam"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    _ "net/http/pprof"
    "os"
    "fahri.com/internal"
)

func main() {
    // go tool pprof http://localhost:6060/debug/pprof/profile
    go func() { log.Println(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:6060", nil)) }()

    modelPath := os.Args[0]
    log.Println(modelPath)

    var datasetPath string
    if len(os.Args) > 2 {
        datasetPath = os.Args[2]
    } else {
        // assuming default path
        datasetPath = "./data"
    }
    log.Println(datasetPath)

    hiddenSize := 100
    _ = hiddenSize

    batchSize := 1
    _ = batchSize

    epochs := 4
    _ = epochs

    rndGen := rand.NewLockedRand(743)
    _ = rndGen

    // read dataset
    trainSet, testSet, err := internal.Load(datasetPath)
    log.Println(trainSet)
    log.Println(testSet)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error reading 'progressive sum' data")
    }

    // model := fn.NewStack(
    //  lstm.New(1, hiddenSize),
    //  linear.New(hiddenSize, 11)
    //  // The CrossEntropy loss doesn't require explicit Softmax activation
    // )

    lstmModel := lstm.New[float32](128, 128)
    _ = lstmModel

    linearModel := linear.New[float32](128, 6925)
    _ = linearModel

    // logits := linearModel.Forward(lstmModel)
    // _ = logits

    // // initialized the new model with random weights
    initRandom(lstmModel, rndGen)

    // // new optimizer with an arbitrary update method
    updater := adam.New[float32](adam.NewDefaultConfig())
    // updater := sgd.New(sgd.NewConfig(0.001, 0.9, true))
    optimizer := gd.NewOptimizer(lstmModel, updater)

    // ad-hoc trainer
    trainer := internal.NewTrainer(model, optimizer, epochs, batchSize, false, trainSet, testSet, modelPath, rndGen)
    trainer.Enjoy() // :)
}
```

but then, this happen

```
internal/evaluator.go:27:10: undefined: ag.NewGraph
internal/evaluator.go:33:16: t.model.NewProc undefined (type nn.Model has no field or method NewProc)
internal/evaluator.go:34:13: undefined: mat.ArgMax
internal/trainer.go:79:45: nn.Apply(t.model) (no value) used as value
internal/trainer.go:79:54: not enough arguments in call to nn.Apply have (nn.Model)
want (nn.Model, func(model nn.Model, name string))
internal/trainer.go:96:15: t.optimizer.Optimize undefined (type *gd.Optimizer has no field or method Optimize)
internal/trainer.go:135:10: g.Clear undefined (type *"github.com/nlpodyssey/spago/ag/encoding".Graph has no field or method Clear)
internal/trainer.go:137:16: t.model.NewProc undefined (type nn.Model has no field or method NewProc)
internal/trainer.go:138:12: g.Div undefined (type *"github.com/nlpodyssey/spago/ag/encoding".Graph has no field or method Div)
internal/trainer.go:138:60: g.NewScalar undefined (type *"github.com/nlpodyssey/spago/ag/encoding".Graph has no field or method NewScalar)
internal/trainer.go:138:60: too many errors
```

I know, it means spago doesn't have NewGraph function anymore on ag module. But, maybe somebody know the similar function for this?

Comment: Github says about this package «forked from nlpodyssey/spago» and that its "master" branch «…is 1594 commits behind nlpodyssey:main» (wich is the (woke-renamed) "master" branch from the original package). 1.5 thouthands commits is a huge changeset, and it's indeed very likely that the original package has changed its API more than once in that series. Hence basically your question is _as stated_ is not answerable:

Comment: …to build a piece of code expecting older API to use a package which has a newer, changed, API amounts to modifying the code to use that newer API. To re-write (or write afresh) a piece of code using some package's API to implements a particular feature ("to build lstm model") means studying what parts of that package's API help creating that feature, and then using them. As you can see, both tasks are essentially the same as when a package's API changes substantially, you can consider it as another, new, package.

Comment: …As a result, you're basically asking for someone to write code for you, instead of attempting that yourself and then asking for help with particular tangible answerable problems you have encountered while trying. The former is not fit for StackOverflow, while the latter is OK. So please take your time, study the API of the "new spago" and then try to figure out how to leverage its API to "build lstm model", then try to actually create one. When you will have a particular problem doing that, come back for help.